# ssh does not return even after execution

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris

The following ssh command does not return to terminal. It hangs though the execution is completed. The execution hangs after echo hi command.

```
ssh user@testserver "echo hello;source .profile;source .bash_profile;/apps/myapp/deploytools/ciInstallAndRun.sh; echo hi"
```

Output

```
hello
<outoutfrom remote script"
hi
```

ciInstallAndRun.sh

```
echo 'starting'
cd /apps/myapp/current
./tctl kill
cd /apps/myapp

mv myapp_v1.0 "myapp_v1.0_`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`"
unzip -o /apps/myapp/myappdist-bin.zip
java -classpath .:/apps/myapp/deploytools/cleanup.jar se.telenor.project.cleanup.Cleanup /apps/myapp myapp_v1.0_ 3
cd /apps/myapp/myapp_v1.0
echo 'Done with deploy'
chmod -R 775 *
echo 'Done'

./tctl start test
```

Source OS: Redhat
Dest Os:  Solaris 10 8/07

Any idea to fix this.

Comment: Fix what?  Which part here is not working? What output do you expect?

Comment: @tripleee. Sorry. The ssh command does not return to terminal. It hangs though the execution is completed. Would you please help.

Comment: So it hangs after `echo hi`?  Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained.

Comment: @tripleee. Yes thats correct. I will.

Comment: Nothing in the code in the question would by itself cause that.  Sounds like an `ssh` problem, or maybe the tool you run from within the script ties up standard input indefinitely.  Try with input redirection; `ssh host 'commands ...' </dev/null`

Comment: @tripleee. Thank you. I tried. Still the same issue. Hangs after echo hi. I had to explicitly exit by Ctrl+D.

Comment: Without access to the other programs you invoke here, there isn't really anything we can do.  This is not a site for debugging in the blind.

Comment: @tripleee - also a child process keeping `stdout` open prevents the session to be closed, e.g `ssh user@host '(sleep 5; echo done) </dev/null &'` only exits afte 5 seconds. `ssh user@host '(sleep 3; echo done) </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &'` exits immediately.

Comment: The long and the short of it is that the OP should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I meant to include `>/dev/null` as well but then the output from the script would be lost.

Comment: *Any idea to fix this.*  Add a `ps -f` command before `echo hi`.  You'll likely see a child process spawned by your install script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Any idea to fix this.*

Your installation script has spawned a child process.

Add a `ps -f` or [`ptree $$`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/ptree-1/index.html) command before `echo hi`.  You'll see a child process or multiple child processes spawned by your install script.

To stop the SSH command from hanging, you need to detach such child process(es) from your terminal's input/output.  You can sedirect your script's output to a file - both `stdout` and `stderr` with `> /some/output/file 2>&1`, and *also* redirect its input with `< /dev/null`.

Or you can use the [`nohup`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/nohup-1/index.html) command.

You haven't provided an MCVE, as others have noted, but this is likely the problem command in you install script, since your question implies that you see the expected output from your install script:

```
./tctl start test
```

You probably would do better to replace it with something like:

```
./tctl start test </dev/null >/some/log/file/path.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thank you. This has fixed the issue.